# What are Boos ghosts of?

Tags: super-mario-brothers

Boos are ghost characters from the Super Mario Bros. franchise. Are boos the lingering spirits of some no longer living creature. Or are they born as boos and have always been ghosts?

Comment: My understanding was that they were the ghosts of children who stayed up past their bedtime playing Nintendo. Is that not canon?

Comment: This question has made me sad. Could they be the victims of a serial killer Italian plumber who had a penchant for murdering his victims by jumping on their heads? It's monstrous I tell you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Per the [Mario Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/boo)

> Goombario's tattle for the Boo Igor in Paper Mario states: *"He probably was a merchant before he became a Boo,"* implying that **current Boos may have once been living beings.**

Comment: Nice! I looked through there and missed that one.

Comment: Normally ghost has they past, so most ghost had a live, before dying.